# How to send String and JsonNode Params from an @FeignClient interface (@RequestParam)?

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices, feign

I have a `microservice` **`employee`** which has a rest end point

`/lookups`
and the method is something like this:

```
@GetMapping("/lookups")
public ResponseEntity<Long> search(
@RequestParam("searchValue") String searchValue,
@RequestParam("externalMap") JsonNode externalMap
) {
        Long searchResult = 2L; //calls searchService(searchValue,externalMap); to get 2L value from DB
        return ResponseEntity.ok(searchResult);
    }
```

I am using an interface `@FeignClient`

```
@FeignClient (name="employee")
public interface EmployeeService {
    @GetMapping("/lookups")
    Long lookupEmployeeService(@RequestParam(value = "searchValue") String searchValue,
            @RequestParam(value = "externalMap") JsonNode externalMap);

}
```

The 2nd service (the one which has `@FeignClient` annotation )gets built and starts without any exceptions.

However, when I use the service `EmployeeService` to fetch the Long value by passing a :

`String searchValue` and a `JsonNode externalMap`,

I get exception :
`HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request (2726ms)`

**Question:**

**1.** What is the right way to call this service and fetch the return value from `Employee Service`?

**2.** Do I need to change the `Signature` of the search method in 1st service?

**3.** How do I overcome this error?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share the Api contract of the Service you are trying to hit ?

Comment: I am not sure what is an Api contract. Could you please tell me where I can find it?

Comment: The `@GetMapping` which you have given at the `EmployeeService` along with the method signature.

Comment: I have already added that in the Question. 

There are 2 code snippets : 
1.  @ GetMapping which is to be consumed
2. @ FeignClient the consumer. 

I need to know how to consume the service, if my method signatures are correct.